# Typescript - clone an object and cast into another type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to clone an untyped object. I want to cast it while cloning.
Here is a very simple code:

```
const typedOject: type123 = {...untypedObject} as type123;
typeObject.a = 1;

export interface type123 {
   a: number;
   b: number;
}
```

But the compiler complains:
Property 'a' does not exist on type 'any[]'

So, why the new object is of type any?

Thanks

Comment: For tasks like this, I typically write a converter function that takes an any object and checks its attributes + builds up the return type

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing where there's a `y` in your above code

Comment: Copied from the development code. Fixed the typo.

Comment: I see. I've added an answer, please let me know if you have any other questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These types of conversions are common for handling API data coming in

Here's how I handle these type of conversions:

#### types/GithubRepo.ts

```js
export interface GithubRepo {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  stars: number;
}

export const convertIntoGithubRepo = (githubRepoFragment: any): GithubRepo => ({
  id: githubRepoFragment.id,
  name: githubRepoFragment.name,
  description: githubRepoFragment.description || '',
  stars: githubRepoFragment.stargazers_count,
});
```

#### Usage

```js
import { convertIntoGithubRepo } from 'types/GithubRepo';


const githubRepo = convertIntoGithubRepo(someGithubRepoFragment);
```

For this example, I am defining a type, then defining methods to copy an object of type `any` over to a type of `GithubRepo`

During this conversion, we can see that I'm checking for a descriptions existence on the `any` object, and adding a blank if one is falsy